# Injected service undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I have 2 `javascript` files, one used as a controller and second as service. When I am injecting service into controller and access it's function, it says

```js
var app = angular.module('currencyConverterModule', []);
app.factory('currencyConverter', function() {

 var localToINR = [
  {USD: 0.015},
  {GBP: 0.011}
 ];

 var convertToLocalCurrency = function (amount, localCurrency) {
  return amount * localToINR[localCurrency];
 }
 
 return { convertToLocalCurrency };
});

var app = angular.module('cartModule', ['currencyConverterModule']);
app.controller('cartController', ['$scope', 'currencyConverter', function ($scope, currencyConverter){

 $scope.SelectedCountry = '0';
 $scope.localCurrency = function(amount, currencyConverter) {
  currencyConverter.convertToLocalCurrency(amount, $scope.SelectedCountry);
 }

 $scope.Products = [
  {name: 'TV', price: $scope.localCurrency(30000), quantity: 1},
  {name: 'Fridge', price: $scope.localCurrency(35000), quantity: 1},
  {name: 'AC', price: $scope.localCurrency(40000), quantity: 1}
 ]; 

 $scope.Countries = [
  {name: 'India', currency: 'INR', currencySymbol: '&#8377'},
  {name: 'United States', currency: 'USD', currencySymbol: '$'},
  {name: 'England', currency: 'GBP', currencySymbol: '&#163;'}
 ]; 

 $scope.getCartValue = function () {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Products.length; i++) {
   total = $scope.Products[i].price * $scope.Products[i].quantity;
  }
  return total;
 }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div ng-app="cartModule" ng-controller="cartController">
  <table ng-hide="SelectedCountry == '0'">
   <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price Per Unit</th>
    <th> Quantity</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="product in Products">
    <td ng-bind="product.name">     
    </td>
    <td ng-bind="product.price | currency : '&#8377'"></td>
    <td>
     <input type="number" ng-model="product.quantity" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td ng-bind="product.price * product.quantity | currency : '&#8377'"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Total</th>
    <th ng-bind="getCartValue() | currency : '&#8377'"></th>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <select ng-model="SelectedCountry">
   <option value="0">Select your country</option>
   <option ng-repeat="country in Countries" ng-value="country.name" ng-bind="country.name"></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</body>
```

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodName' of undefined

**Service**

```
var app = angular.module('currencyConverterModule', []);
app.factory('currencyConverter', function() {

    var localToINR = [
        {USD: 0.015},
        {GBP: 0.011}
    ];

    var convertToLocalCurrency = function (amount, localCurrency) {
        return amount * localToINR[localCurrency];
    }

    return { convertToLocalCurrency };
});
```

and **Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('cartModule', ['currencyConverterModule']);
app.controller('cartController', ['currencyConverter', function ($scope, currencyConverter){

    $scope.SelectedCountry = '0';
    $scope.localCurrency = function(amount, currencyConverter) {
        currencyConverter.convert(amount, $scope.SelectedCountry); //Error here
    }

    $scope.Products = [
        {name: 'TV', price: $scope.localCurrency(30000), quantity: 1},
        {name: 'Fridge', price: $scope.localCurrency(35000), quantity: 1},
        {name: 'AC', price: $scope.localCurrency(40000), quantity: 1}
    ];  

    $scope.Countries = [
        {name: 'India', currency: 'INR', currencySymbol: '&#8377'},
        {name: 'United States', currency: 'USD', currencySymbol: '$'},
        {name: 'England', currency: 'GBP', currencySymbol: '&#163;'}
    ];  

    $scope.getCartValue = function () {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Products.length; i++) {
            total = $scope.Products[i].price * $scope.Products[i].quantity;
        }
        return total;
    }
}]);
```

I have tried adding both files in different order in view but that couldn't solve the problem. What I am doing wrong here?

I am referencing 3 js files in HTML as below

```
<script src="../Script/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../Services/currencyConverter.js"></script>
<script src="../Script/cartController.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed to inject **`$scope`**,

```
app.controller('cartController', ['$scope','currencyConverter', function ($scope, currencyConverter)
```

and the method name is **`convertToLocalCurrency`** not just **`convert`**

```
currencyConverter.convertToLocalCurrency(amount, $scope.SelectedCountry);
```

**EDIT**

You're getting undefined because your function parameter name is also **`currencyConverter`** , you need to change it to something else or remove it completely since you are not using,

```
$scope.localCurrency = function(amount, currency) {
    currencyConverter.convertToLocalCurrency(amount, $scope.SelectedCountry);
}
```

[`WORKING DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/6BbTu0wHUBXFNQtB4YiB?p=preview)

Also i modified your service a bit to return the factory with the methods as

```
var app = angular.module('currencyConverterModule', []);
app.factory('currencyConverter', function() {
  var dataFactory={};
    var localToINR = [
        {USD: 0.015},
        {GBP: 0.011}
    ];

    dataFactory.convertToLocalCurrency = function (amount, localCurrency) {
        return amount * localToINR[localCurrency];
    }

    return dataFactory ;
});
```

Comment: Tried, still getting same error. Also I am not able to understand why we have to write both dependencies twice.

Comment: check the updated answer, it matters because number of parameters

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I corrected function name but still getting same error with new function name. Function was not important I guess because error says service instance is undefined

Comment: thats strange! can you post how you are referencing the js files in html

Comment: so currencyConverter.js is the service module?

Answer (score 1):

The `$scope.localCurrency` function erroneously has two parameters:

```
app.controller('cartController', ['$scope', 'currencyConverter',
  function ($scope, currencyConverter){    
    $scope.SelectedCountry = '0';
    $̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶l̶o̶c̶a̶l̶C̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶c̶y̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶a̶m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶c̶y̶C̶o̶n̶v̶e̶r̶t̶e̶r̶)̶ ̶{
    $scope.localCurrency = function(amount) {
        currencyConverter.convertToLocalCurrency(amount, $scope.SelectedCountry);
    }
```

The `currencyConverter` factory is injected in controller construction function, not in the local scope function.

## The DEMO

```js
var app = angular.module('currencyConverterModule', []);
app.factory('currencyConverter', function() {

 var localToINR = [
  {USD: 0.015},
  {GBP: 0.011}
 ];

 var convertToLocalCurrency = function (amount, localCurrency) {
  return amount * localToINR[localCurrency];
 }
 
 return { convertToLocalCurrency };
});

var app = angular.module('cartModule', ['currencyConverterModule']);
app.controller('cartController', ['$scope', 'currencyConverter', function ($scope, currencyConverter){

 $scope.SelectedCountry = '0';
 $scope.localCurrency = function(amount) {
  currencyConverter.convertToLocalCurrency(amount, $scope.SelectedCountry);
 }

 $scope.Products = [
  {name: 'TV', price: $scope.localCurrency(30000), quantity: 1},
  {name: 'Fridge', price: $scope.localCurrency(35000), quantity: 1},
  {name: 'AC', price: $scope.localCurrency(40000), quantity: 1}
 ]; 

 $scope.Countries = [
  {name: 'India', currency: 'INR', currencySymbol: '&#8377'},
  {name: 'United States', currency: 'USD', currencySymbol: '$'},
  {name: 'England', currency: 'GBP', currencySymbol: '&#163;'}
 ]; 

 $scope.getCartValue = function () {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Products.length; i++) {
   total = $scope.Products[i].price * $scope.Products[i].quantity;
  }
  return total;
 }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <div ng-app="cartModule" ng-controller="cartController">
  <table ng-hide="SelectedCountry == '0'">
   <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Price Per Unit</th>
    <th> Quantity</th>
    <th>Total Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="product in Products">
    <td ng-bind="product.name">     
    </td>
    <td ng-bind="product.price | currency : '&#8377'"></td>
    <td>
     <input type="number" ng-model="product.quantity" min="0" max="100">
    </td>
    <td ng-bind="product.price * product.quantity | currency : '&#8377'"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Total</th>
    <th ng-bind="getCartValue() | currency : '&#8377'"></th>
   </tr>
  </table>

  <select ng-model="SelectedCountry">
   <option value="0">Select your country</option>
   <option ng-repeat="country in Countries" ng-value="country.name" ng-bind="country.name"></option>
  </select>
 </div>
</body>
```